# Better: string html generation vs jquery DOM element creation performance wise?

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
 var str = '<table class="bndotamntbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">';
        str += '<tbody>';

        /*Create Header [Properties]*/
        str += '<tr>';
  str += '<td>'; SOME CONTENT


dv.innerHTML = str ;
```

VS

```
  var tbl = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "tblContent" },{cellspacing: "0" },{cellpadding: "0"},{border: "0"}).addClass("bndotamntbl");
 $('<div>').attr({id:}).append(tbl);
```

Better: string html generation vs jquery DOM element creation performance wise ?Please explain ..

Comment: it's probably not noticeable unless you're doing this in mass quantities. You can always test yourself on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: Suppose i have a large dom then which one is better ..?

Answer (score 0):

First one would be added to DOM when this `dv.innerHTML = str;` executes, but in later example, with `$('<table></table>')` you are adding the node to the DOM at the same time.

As most of template engines, such as Mustache.js etc. do (which compiles the html string), first scenario is seems okay.